# Why does my array element retrieval function return random value?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to make an own simple string implementation in C++. My implementation is not `\0` delimited, but uses the first element in my character array (the data structure I have chosen to implement the string) as the length of the string.

In essence, I have this as my data structure: `typedef char * arrayString;` and I have got the following as the implementation of some primal string manipulating routines:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

#include "new_string.h"

// Our string implementation will store the
// length of the string in the first byte of
// the string.
int getLength(const arrayString &s1) {
    return s1[0] - '0';
}

void append_str(arrayString &s, char c) {
    int length = getLength(s);              // get the length of our current string
    length++;                               // account for the new character
    arrayString newString = new char[length]; // create a new heap allocated string
    newString[0] = length;
    // fill the string with the old contents
    for (int counter = 1; counter < length; counter++) {
        newString[counter] = s[counter];
    }
    // append the new character
    newString[length - 1] = c;

    delete[] s;                             // prevent a memory leak
    s = newString;
}

void display(const arrayString &s1) {
    int max = getLength(s1);
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= max; counter++) {
        std::cout << s1[counter];
    }
}

void appendTest() {
    arrayString a = new char[5];
    a[0] = '5'; a[1] = 'f'; a[2] = 'o'; a[3] = 't'; a[4] = 'i';
    append_str(a, 's');
    display(a);
}
```

My issue is with the implementation of my function `getLength()`. I have tried to debug my program inside Visual Studio, and all seems nice and well in the beginning.

The first time `getLength()` is called, inside the `append_str()` function, it returns the correct value for the string length (5). When it get's called inside the `display()`, my own custom string displaying function (to prevent a bug with `std::cout`), it reads the value (`6`) correctly, but returns **`-42`**? What's going on?

[image]

**NOTES**

1. Ignore my comments in the code. It's purely educational and it's just me trying to see what level of commenting improves the code and what level reduces its quality.
2. In `get_length()`, I had to do `first_element - '0'` because otherwise, the function would return the ascii value of the arithmetic value inside. For instance, for decimal `6`, it returned `54`.
3. This is an educational endeavour, so if you see anything else worth commenting on, or fixing, by all means, let me know.

Comment: You set the breakpoint before `max` was initialized. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the `-'0'` that is messing you up because `'0'` is decimal 48 so 6-48= -42.

Comment: Please do not have a `typedef char * arrayString;` to declare a Pascal string. You should give it an own class/structure.

Comment: @bytecode77 Nope. At least I don't think so. See, it the debugger's Auto's field that `getLength` returned `-42`

Comment: Why don't you store the size as an interger value in the char (max portable size 127 characters) instead of the actual character code?

Comment: why are you doing -'0'? how do you specify length of string as 12 in your case?

Comment: @NeilKirk I just noticed me doing that in the tester function I made. I don't know how to feel right now... I will check it out and report back.

Comment: @DigitalNinja You are right, the first element is a size information and should not be treated as a character.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and a good debug compiler (VS counts) and it will trigger asserts as soon as you go out of bounds.

Comment: cast `length` to `char` before you assign it to `newString[0]` in `append_str`.  You are storing `length` as an integer in `newString` and everything else as a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you everyone for helping me out.

The problem appeared to be inside the `appendTest()` function, where I was storing in the first element of the array the character code for the value I wanted to have as a size (i.e storing `'5'` instead of just `5`). It seems that I didn't edit previous code that I had correctly, and that's what caused me the issues.

**As an aside** to what many of you are asking, *why am I not using classes or better design*, it's because I want to implement a basic string structure having many constraints, such as no classes, etc. I basically want to use only arrays, and the most I am affording myself is to make them dynamically allocated, i.e resizable.

Comment: A step back to history, maybe?

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes. Implementing a lot of stuff will allow me (hopefully) to grow more accustomed to C++ and in the meantime, have better perspective regarding systems design.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are getting the length as `return s1[0] - '0';` in `getLength()` you should set then length as `newString[0] = length + '0';` instead of `newString[0] = length;`

As a side why are you storing the size of the string in the array?  why not have some sort of integer member that you store the size in.  A couple of bytes really isn't going to hurt and now you have a string that can be more than 256 characters long.

Comment: An old fashion Pascal string, might be the reason.

Comment: @DieterLücking I have never used pascal so I didn't know they did that.  Does that limit the size of strings in Pascal?

Comment: @NathanOliver It did limit the character length, at least it did the last time I used Pascal back in the "Turbo" days.

Comment: Yes - simple pascal strings are limited to 255 characters

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing your array out of bounds at couple of places.

**In `append_str`**

```
for (int counter = 1; counter < length; counter++) {
    newString[counter] = s[counter];
}
```

In the example you presented, the starting string is "5foti" -- without the terminating null character. The maximum valid index is `4`. In the above function, `length` has already been set to `6` and you are accessing `s[5]`.

This can be fixed by changing the conditional in the `for` statement to `counter < length-1;`

**And in `display`.**

```
int max = getLength(s1);
for (int counter = 1; counter <= max; counter++) {
    std::cout << s1[counter];
}
```

Here again, you are accessing the array out of bounds by using `counter <= max` in the loop.

This can be fixed by changing the conditional in the `for` statement to `counter < max;`

Comment: newString[length - 1] = c; - this don't make sense either as that value was assigned previously in loop; ps are you sure 2nd case is out of bounds? if "3abs" then valid index is 1,2,3

Comment: @Giorgi, The example used suggests that they will use `"4abs"`, not `"3abs"`.

Comment: @R Sahu: ok for me latter makes more sense though

Comment: It makes more sense to use `"3abs"`.

Comment: @Giorgi, If `"3abs"` is used, then the second block of code will be correct but other parts of the code will be incorrect.

Comment: @R Sahu: yeah like this is weird:     newString[length - 1] = c; - above in loop this value was already written to

Answer (score 1):

Here are some improvements, that should also cover your question:

1. Instead of a typedef, define a class for your string. The class should have an `int` for the length and a `char*` for the string data itself.
2. Use operator overloads in your class "string" so you can append them with `+` etc.
3. The `- '0'` gives me pain. You subtract the ASCII value of 42 from the length, but you do not add it as a character. Also, the length can be 127 at maximum, because char goes from -128 to +127. See point #1.
4. `append_str` changes the pointer of your object. That's very bad practice!